# What this automaton about

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Given is a (finite state) automaton $M=(\{0,1,2,3\},\{0,1\},d,0,\{2\})$

where
$$d(0,0)=0, d(1,0)=1,d(2,0)=2,d(3,0)=3,d(0,1)=1,\\ d(1,1)=2,d(2,1)=3,d(3,1)=0$$

I need to find what language this automaton accepts.

after I draw I got `0*10*1(10*10*10*1+0)*` using Thompson construction
is this automata, will accept all strings, that have 2 "1" in it and 4 "1" in it?

since node 2 will accept the language after 2 "1" appear,  i was confuse what happen after there is `111111` or `1111` after pass node 2.

Comment: What type of automaton is $M$? How does the $d$ function mean (some transition function)? As formulated the question is unclear.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma d is transition symbol , as M i dont know i just draw the automata

Comment: automata is plural, its singular is automaton.

Comment: So $4$ states $0,1,2,3$ input alphabet $\{0,1\}$, state $0$ is the starting state, state $2$ the accepting state and $d(i,j)$ is the state we move to after reading symbol $j$ when in state $i$ ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Yes but d(1,0)=1 means after 1 and get input 0 then we move to 1

Comment: "after 1" means when  in state 1, I suppose.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  yes when in state i get input j go to k d(i,j)=k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clear that $0$'s have no effect on the state, as $d(i,0)=i$ for all $i$.

So to reach an end state we need to see 2 $1$'s: to get to state 1 and then to state 2. If we see one more we move to 3 and stay there, only to restart at 0 when we see another 1. We've then seen 4 1's and are back at the start. So we reach 2 precisely when we have 2, 6, 10 or in general $4n+2$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ $1$'s in the string.

In regular expression terms a possible solution could be $0^\ast10^\ast10^\ast(10^\ast10^\ast10^\ast10^\ast)^\ast$: precisely 1 group with $2$ 1's followed by 0 or more groups with exactly $4$ 1's.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I would like to know how you derive the regular expressions? Why you concatenate the string 0*10*10*   And (0*10*10*10*10*)* ? And why it have kleene star on it? Is it by inspection? Why 0*10*10* dont have kleene star too(?)

Comment: @fiksx Just common sense. The first $0^\ast$ inside the brackets could go, as long as we do have it before the brackets. I edited it, it's more clean. the build-up is just "group with 2 1's"(group with 4 1's)*" really. The last ensures that we have the extra 4/8/12 etc 1's required to get accepted.

Comment: i understand  thankyou , is it the same with 0*10*1(10*10*10*1+0)* ? as before the first bracket  this accept two 1, but inside bracket  0*10*110*10*10*1，there is double one in the middle, is this wrong(?)

Comment: @fiksx that first one is not quite correct. There could be 0’s at the end of the group with 2 or 0’s at the start of a group with 4. 2 consecutive 1s is surely not correct. We can always stuff 0’s in between.

Comment: ok,thankyou so much! i would like to ask one more thing after it accept 11 for example , when the input after it 1 again,such that 111111 it will go from state 0->1->2->3->0->1->2 then accept the string or it will automaticaly accept all string start with 11? is this dfa?

Comment: @fiksx when you’re in an accepting state when the input ends, the string is accepted, and only then. It’s indeed a DFA, or what I’ve learnt as a finite state automaton, of the simplest type.